# Simple Client/Server C program not correctly communicating

Tags: c, client-server

I'm trying to set up a client/server program in C and have everything compiling but I can't get it to output correctly. Currently, it only outputs my printf statements and not the actual string inputted in the client. It's supposed to have the client take in three strings and send them to the server, which checks to see if they're all lowercase characters. If not, output an invalid string message. If so, count the number of vowels, and send all results to the client. It looks correct to me but I don't get why it isn't working.
Client code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct Client
{
  int l[1];          // stores number of vowels
  int m[1];          // stores number of vowels
  int n[1];          // stores number of vowels  
  char charbuff1[6]; // buffer holds a character
  char outchar1[7];  // server puts string here
  char charbuff2[6]; // buffer holds a character
  char outchar2[7];  // server puts string here
  char charbuff3[6]; // buffer holds a character
  char outchar3[7];  // server puts string here
}
inst;
main (void)
{
  memset(inst.charbuff1,0,6);
  memset(inst.outchar1,0,7);
  memset(inst.charbuff2,0,6);
  memset(inst.outchar2,0,7);
  memset(inst.charbuff3,0,6);
  memset(inst.outchar3,0,7);
  int fda; // to write to server
  int fdb; // to read response from server
  struct Client;
  int i;

  if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_WRONLY))<0) //open fifo to write to server
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

  if((fdb=open("FIFO2", O_RDONLY))<0) //open fifo to read from server
     printf("cant open fifo to read");

  printf("Client: Please enter up to 6 lowercase characters: ");
  for(i=0;i<6;i++) //for loop to take the first input
  {
    scanf("%c", &inst.charbuff1[i]);
  }
  printf("Client: Please enter up to 6 lowercase characters: ");
  for(i=0;i<6;i++) //for loop to take the second input
  {
    scanf("%c", &inst.charbuff2[i]);
  }
  printf("Client: Please enter up to 6 lowercase characters: ");
  for(i=0;i<6;i++) //for loop to take the third input
  {
    scanf("%c", &inst.charbuff3[i]);
  }
  write(fda, &inst, sizeof(inst)); //write results to the struct

  printf("\nClient: Got the characters sent, now waiting for response ");
  read(fdb, &inst, sizeof(inst)); //read results from server struct
  printf("\nClient: received from server %s", inst.outchar1);
  printf("\nClient: Was this a valid string? ");
  if(inst.l[1] = 9) //check if first string had an invalid character
  {
    printf("No");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Yes");
    printf("\nClient: The number of vowels in the string is: %d", inst.l[1]);
  }
  printf("\nClient: The number of vowels in the string is: %d", inst.l[1]);

  printf("\nClient: received from server %s", inst.outchar2);
  printf("\nClient: Was this a valid string? ");
  if(inst.m[1] = 9) //check if second string had an invalid character
  {
    printf("No");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Yes");
    printf("\nClient: The number of vowels in the string is: %d", inst.m[1]);
  }
  printf("\nClient: received from server %s", inst.outchar3);
  printf("\nClient: Was this a valid string? ");
  if(inst.n[1] = 9) //check if third string had an invalid character
  {
    printf("No");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Yes");
    printf("\nClient: The number of vowels in the string is: %d", inst.n[1]);
  }

  close(fda);
  close(fdb);

  printf ("\nall done!\n");

}
```

Server code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct Server
{
  int l[1];          // stores number of vowels
  int m[1];          // stores number of vowels
  int n[1];          // stores number of vowels
  char charbuff1[6]; // buffer holds a character
  char outchar1[7];  // server puts string here
  char charbuff2[6]; // buffer holds a character
  char outchar2[7];  // server puts string here
  char charbuff3[6]; // buffer holds a character
  char outchar3[7];  // server puts string here
}
  inst;
  main (void)
  {
  memset(inst.charbuff1,0,6);
  memset(inst.outchar1,0,7);
  memset(inst.charbuff2,0,6);
  memset(inst.outchar2,0,7);
  memset(inst.charbuff3,0,6);
  memset(inst.outchar3,0,7);
  struct Server;
  int i;
  int fda;      // to read from client
  int fdb;      // to write to client

  /* Create the fifos and open them  */
  if ((mkfifo("FIFO1",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
    perror("cant create FIFO1");
    exit(-1);
    }

   if ((mkfifo("FIFO2",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
    perror("cant create FIFO2");
    exit(-1);
    }

  if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

  if((fdb=open("FIFO2", O_WRONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to read");

  read(fda, &inst, sizeof(inst)); //read the struct from client


  for( i = 0; i<6; i++) //for loop to write the first string from charbuff array to outchar array
  {
    inst.outchar1[i] = inst.charbuff1[i];
    inst.outchar1[6] = 0;
  }
  printf("\nServer: first string is: %s", inst.outchar1);

  inst.l[1] = 0;

  for( i = 0; i<6; i++) //for loop to check for non-lowercase characters
  {
  if(inst.outchar1[i] < 'a' && inst.outchar1[i] > 'z') //if a character isn't lowercase, set l to 9
  {
    inst.l[1] = 9;
    break;
  }
  else if(inst.outchar1[i] = 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') //if a character is a vowel, increment l by 1
  {
    inst.l[1]++;
  }
  else //if a character is a lowercase consonant, do nothing
  {
   inst.l[1];
  }
  }
  printf("\nServer: Checked for uppercase letters");

  if(inst.l[1] = 9) //if an invalid character was encountered
  {
    printf("\nServer: There are uppercase letters");
  }
  else //if no invalid character was encountered
  {
    printf("\nServer: There are no uppercase letters");
    printf("\nServer: The humber of vowels are: %d", inst.l[1]);
  }

  for( i = 0; i<6; i++) //for loop to write the second string from charbuff array to outchar array
  {
    inst.outchar2[i] = inst.charbuff2[i];
    inst.outchar2[6] = 0;
  }
  printf("\nServer: second string is: %s", inst.outchar2);

  inst.m[1] = 0;

  for( i = 0; i<6; i++) //for loop to check for non-lowercase characters
  {
  if(inst.outchar1[i] < 'a' && inst.outchar1[i] > 'z') //if a character isn't lowercase, set m to 9
  {
    inst.m[1] = 9;
    break;
  }
  else if(inst.outchar2[i] = 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') //if a character is a vowel, increment m by 1
  {
    inst.m[1]++;
  }
  else //if a character is a lowercase consonant, do nothing
  {
    inst.m[1];
  }
  }
  printf("\nServer: Checked for uppercase letters");

  if(inst.m[1] = 9) //if an invalid character was encountered
  {
    printf("\nServer: There are uppercase letters");
  }
  else //if no invalid character was encountered
  {
    printf("\nServer: There are no uppercase letters");
    printf("\nServer: The humber of vowels are: %d", inst.m[1]);
  }

  for( i = 0; i<6; i++) //for loop to write the third string from charbuff array to outchar array
  {
    inst.outchar3[i] = inst.charbuff3[i];
    inst.outchar3[6] = 0;
  }
  printf("\nServer: third string is: %s", inst.outchar3);

  inst.n[1] = 0;

  for( i = 0; i<6; i++) //for loop to check for non-lowercase characters
  {
  if(inst.outchar1[i] < 'a' && inst.outchar1[i] > 'z') //if a character isn't lowercase, set n to 9
  {
    inst.n[1] = 9;
    break;
  }
  else if(inst.outchar3[i] = 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') //if a character is a vowel, increment n by 1
  {
    inst.n[1]++;
  }
  else
  {
    inst.n[1]; //if a character is a lowercase consonant, do nothing
  }
  }
  printf("\nServer: Checked for uppercase letters");

  if(inst.n[1] = 9) //if an invalid character was encountered
  {
    printf("\nServer: There are uppercase letters");
  }
  else //if no invalid character was encountered
  {
    printf("\nServer: There are no uppercase letters");
    printf("\nServer: The humber of vowels are: %d", inst.n[1]);
  }
  write(fdb, &inst, sizeof(inst));
  printf("\nServer: This says I am ready to close.\n ");

  close(fda);
  close(fdb);
  unlink("FIFO1");
  unlink("FIFO2");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: In the client program you're not skipping over the newline at the end of each line of input.

Comment: Also, it says to enter up to 6 characters, but the user has to enter exactly 6 characters -- there's no way for them to signal that they're done. Maybe you should use `fgets()` to read a line at a time, instead of `scanf()` to read a character at a time.

Comment: My expected input is three strings of exactly 6 alphabetical characters. The expected output is the three strings of six characters entered, if the string had only lowercase characters, and if so, the number of vowels in the string. My current output is this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/1kLIk0V.png)

Comment: I changed my code to replace the size one arrays to check the vowels to just be an int and changed the for loops to be fgets() statements and my code now partially works [output](http://i.imgur.com/0K9gEbq.png) [current server code](http://pastebin.com/LtgQqWYL) [current client code](http://pastebin.com/vAdj99fC)